# setInterval in document.ready not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

```
$(document).ready(function(){

setInterval(test(), 1000);

    function test(){ alert('hi'); }

});
```

Why the code above triggers `test()` just on document ready and not every second? Jsfiddle demo: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xmm7b/).

Comment: I think the function isn't defined when you call "setInterval". Also, it should be test, not test()

Comment: "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" might be the reason. Not to mention, this is definitely a duplicate, now just to find one of the other hundred times this was asked.

Comment: off course. I wasn't referring to you. Btw, now it works fine so I guess it is not relevant where you define a function in this case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you include the brackets `()` it executes the function, you want to pass `setInterval` a reference to what function it should call every second, which is just `test`

```
setInterval(test, 1000); //no parenthesis
```

The new (now rather annoying) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmokeyPHP/xmm7b/1/)

Comment: or if you want to call it as test you can call test inside an anonymous function setInterval(function(){test();}, 1000)

Comment: @Saturnix No worries, just think of it as `setInterval` automatically putting `()` after whatever you put as the first param!

Comment: @Saturnix Also, remember to click the tick to the left of the answer to accept and close off the question as resolved for future users!

Comment: I can't do that right now, SO needs a few minutes before you can accept an answer.

Comment: @Saturnix Ah yes, of course - just making sure you're aware, lots of users get their answer then don't come back and accept it!

Comment: That's what's death penalty for!

Comment: @Saturnix Indeed! {rudeWord}s ...

Answer (score 3):

```
function test(){ alert('hi'); }
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(test, 1000);   
});
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzfdw/)